# openseadragon background request's accept header

Tags: firefox, openseadragon

in a Linked Data context, I am pointing my openseadragon client to a resource that will respond with a 303 redirection. If OSD's request has a header "Accept: image/*" (with virtually anything for '*'), the redirection will point to a jpeg and everything is fine. This is the way it works in google chrome.

However, in Firefox the request seems somehow to have a header "Accept: */*". At least that's how I am interpreting the output of firefox's developer's tools' network panel. This leads the resource at the end to redirect to a html page which, of course, OSD cannot render as an image.

How could this happen?

The way I embed OSD in my webpage is like this:

```
var Imageviewer = OpenSeadragon({
    debugMode:              false,
    id:                     "contentDiv",
    prefixUrl:              "resources/img/SeaDragonImages/",
    showNavigator:          true,
    autoHideControls:       false,
    autoResize:             true,
    springStiffness:        10,
    preserveViewport:       true,
//  ajaxHeaders: {'Accept: image/jpeg'},
    tileSources: null          // sources are (re-)loaded when pageNumbers are clicked
});
$(function(){
    $(".pageNo").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        Imageviewer.open({
            type: 'legacy-image-pyramid',
            levels: [{ url: $(this).attr('href'), <span data-template="app:scaleImg"/> }]
        });
    });
});
```

Note that if I enable the `ajaxHeaders: {'Accept: image/jpeg'},` that is presently commented out, I do get an Accept header but it contains all sorts of text/hmtl; application/xhtml and the like.

Comment: I found out that, according to [this mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values), firefox defaults to \*/\* (since Firefox 47) for images. Which leads to said problems. When I change `image.http.accept` to something more meaningful, it's working.But of course I cannot change my guest's configuration, so I need to find a way to get past firefox's default when running OSD...

Comment: I know a lot about OpenSeadragon, but not much about the finer points of http requests, so I may not be of much help. Does OpenSeadragon's recently added AJAX-based tile loading feature help at all? Is there some other change that could be made to OpenSeadragon that would help with this issue?

Comment: I tried it and it did not run into firefox's \*/\* default image type because it does not request an image in the first place. However, I could not get a configuration ready for ajax to use: I do not know enough about setting up tile sources and their description, so I am using the 'legacy-image-pyramid' type of sources, because I am assuming this is the only type that can ingest a simple image file instead of a configuration of tile sources. AFAIU, the ajax-based tile loading requires some more sophisticated data to be fetchable, right?

Comment: I am not sure I was looking at the right places, but when I tried to find the relevant points in openseadragon.js, I got stuck at the assigment of `this.image.src = this.src;` in ImageJob.prototype/start in line 16118. I could not track it further. Does openseadragon leave the rest of work of loading the resource to firefox or does it build a request itself (as it does in the Ajax case)?

Comment: Another way to test/verify the issue: In [openseadragonizer](http://openseadragon.github.io/openseadragonizer), open the resource http://id.salamanca.school/works.W0004:frontmatter.pFOL1R - In chrome it's working, in firefox it is not.

Comment: Yes, for legacy tile source I believe we do just leave it to the browser after `this.image.src = ...`. I would think that the browser would normally load even a redirected image properly. The OpenSeadragonizer repro is great; definitely shows the issue. Interesting that if you go to that URL in the browser it takes you to a full webpage. Do you have control over that server? What if you used a different redirect type? I'm noticing in the Firefox network tab that the redirect seems to cascade to four other HTML pages (unlike on Chrome).

Comment: Yes, the server is under my control. The URI represents a "page" and the server redirects depending on the content that the client accepts: If the client accepts (only) images, the redirection points to an image of the page, if the client accepts (x)html, it points to the page's transcription. If a client says it accepts anything, the redirection goes to the html resource by default. In all cases, LOD content negotiation conventionally uses 303 status codes. (The cascade has to do with http/https redirection and language selection, kicking in only in the html case.)

Comment: If we cannot hook into firefox's request via Openseadragon (and ajax is not currently possible because of the limited offer on our image server's side), probably we might switch from plain image files served via http to something more elaborate. I am having iiif on my mind...

Comment: Do you have an example of a non-OSD way to load an image with this system using firefox? If so, presumably OSD could be adapted to support the technique. On the other hand, while the "1 URL for all types" thing is clever, I'm not sure I understand why it's necessary... why not a different URL for images directly?

Comment: Ian, I don't have an example ready. And I think it makes more sense for us to invest the effort in establishing an iiif image service than in building a javascript image viewer with hand-crafted http get request just in order to have an example. I thought the solution was easier or the problem more common. So while the problem is not really solved, I think I have a way forward with it. Thank you a lot for trying to understand the situation and for offering help, I do appreciate it.

Comment: Okay, sounds good... as long as you end up with what you need! :)